# java.lang.assertionError: expected "updated" but was "value"

Tags: java

i am having three methods in my test case. 1.add 2.update

while i am updating i am using the following code in my test case

```
@Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testUpdateCoupon() {
        CouponDO couponDO = getCoupon();
        try {
            couponDAOImpl.addCoupon(couponDO);
            couponDO.setType(2);
            couponDAOImpl.addCoupon(couponDO);
            couponDAOImpl.getCoupon(couponDO.getDiscountId());
            couponDAOImpl.updateCoupon(couponDO);
            Assert.assertEquals("Coupon updated", couponDO.getType());
        } catch (CrafartDataException cdExp) {
            cdExp.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }
```

but it shows an error java.lang.assertionError: expected  but was<2>(

Answer (score 2):

From code it seems that you are checking equality for `Coupon updated` and `2`, as per the code you are setting `type` equal to 2. If you're using `enum` then you can use String value of `enum` for 2, else you will need to use `2` instead of `Coupon updated`.

Comment: so what should i do for update the coupon. here i am trying to update the "type". so what i have to change in my code

Comment: Is the String `Coupon updated` set in any property of the object `couponDO`?

Comment: coupon updated is a message to show . its not set to any property

Comment: Then why are you checking that for Assertion, if you need to show its should not be used in assertion. Assertion should be use to verify if you're condition is satisfied or not.